# Generate random click events

Tags: jquery

I want to be able to randomize click events on buttons in a list of items. I have seen similar code for adding classes, but I need to simulate random click events over the list of items.

```js
$(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
  });
  $(".item").each(function(i, e) {
    var button = $(this).find("button");
    ranNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * (6 - 2 + 1)) + 2;
    if ((i + 1) % ranNum == 0) {
      $(e).button.click();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.active {
  background: green
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
  <button>Button 1</button>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <button>Button 2</button>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <button>Button 3</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Err, to click the button would be `button.click()` or `button.trigger('click')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of triggering the click event you can reuse the anonymous function by storing it in a variable, let's call it `toggleActive`

We can apply `this`to our function with the [call method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call#)

```js
$(function() {
  var toggleActive = function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
  };
  $("button").click(toggleActive);
  $(".item").each(function(i, e) {
    var button = $(this).find("button");
    ranNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * (6 - 2 + 1)) + 2;
    if ((i + 1) % ranNum == 0) {
      toggleActive.call(button);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.active {
  background: green
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
  <button>Button 1</button>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <button>Button 2</button>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <button>Button 3</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(function () {
        $(".item").each(function (i, e) {
            var button = $("button", this);
            ranNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * (6 - 2 + 1)) + 2;
            if ((i + 1) % ranNum == 0) {
                $(button).click(function () { active(this); });
            }
        });
    });
    function active(e) {
        $(e).toggleClass("active");
    }
```